# How to keep position of elements in background image while resize

Tags: html, css, responsive

This is my code html and css [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hendro/7oacu1nw/8/)

I tried to make all element stay on background when i'm resizing, but every element chaos when i resize, this my code:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
* {padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow-x: hidden;}

img.road {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0%;
}

img.ppl {
  width: 3.6%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 255px;
  top: 535px;
}

@keyframes moveCar {
  from {left: -100%;}
  to   {left: 100%;}
}
```

anybody can help? very appreciate thanks

Comment: You've set your ppl and road to absolute positions with static numbers defining their distance from the left and top... Try making the positions relative and the distances percents.

Comment: sorry for bother you, but can you help me, to change code in my fiddle link? @SydneyY

Comment: First, you need take a small grass image and repeat it in background (behind background image) and then you need to customize media queries for all screen to adjust position of elements for all screen

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text

Comment: could you change in my fiddle? @waqas

Comment: @nourza yes, like that i want, but when I change position that chaos